# How to compute direct images of ramified covering maps?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, line-bundles

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety, $L$ a line bundle on $X$, and $s \in \Gamma(X,L) $ a non-zero section whose zero locus $D$ is smooth.

Let $\pi: Y \to X$ be the $n$-sheeted ramified cover given in local coordinates by taking the $n$-th roots of the section $s$.

How do we compute the direct image $\pi_* \mathcal{O}_Y$? In particular, I would like to know why this is a direct sum of various powers of $L$.

A second related question: How do we compute the direct image $\pi_* \mathbf{C}_Y$ where $\mathbf{C}_Y$ denotes the constant sheaf on $Y$ with complex coefficients?

Comment: It is not sum of powers of $L$, at least not integer powers. I suggest you calculate the case of the projective line and the double cover simply ramified at two points ( so $L=O(2)$).

Comment: @Mohan in your example, $ L $ has a square root, $ O(1) $, so isn't the double cover ramified at two points (the zero locus of a general global section $ s $ of $ O(2) $) given by the relative spec, $ \operatorname{Spec} (O \oplus O(-1)) $, where the algebra structure is obvious except for that on $ O(-1) \otimes O(-1) $ where it's $ (u,v) \rightarrow suv \in O $. So in this case what the OP asks is true.

Comment: I think the problem is exactly the fact that $ L $ may not have a n-th root, as your comment indirectly alludes to. Otherwise if $ L = M^n $, then the pushforward of the structure sheaf is $ O \oplus M^{-1} \oplus \cdots \oplus M^{-n+1} $.

Comment: @CraniumClamp How do we compute this result? Let's assume $L$ admits an $n$-th root. It seems you are saying that the pushforward should be the same as the relative spec.

Comment: @Bun I wrote down some details, if something isn't clear let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume that $ L = M^n $ for some line bundle $ M $ and let $ N = M^{-1} $. We'll show that $ \underline{\operatorname{Spec}} (\mathcal{O}_X \oplus N \oplus \cdots \oplus N^{n-1} )$ is the desired $ n $-sheeted cover of $ X $, ramified exactly along $ Y $. The result then follows from the fact that for any quasicoherent sheaf of algebras $ \mathcal{A} $ on $ X $ and $ \pi : Y = \underline{\operatorname{Spec}} \mathcal{A} \rightarrow X $ the structure map, $ \pi_* \mathcal{O}_Y = \mathcal{A} $.

First, the algebra structure on $ \mathcal{O}_X \oplus N \oplus \cdots \oplus N^{n-1} $ is given by the obvious way $ N^i \otimes N^j \rightarrow N^{i+j} $ when $ i+ j < n $ and $ N^i \otimes N^j \rightarrow N^{i+j-n} $ when $ i+j \ge n $ by $ (u,v) \rightarrow suv $. Now it's easy to see that the relative spec is indeed the correct object: Let $ U = \operatorname{Spec} A \subset X $ be an open affine on which $ N $ is trivialized, hence so is $ L $. Since $ X $ is integral, $ L $ is a Cartier divisor so let $ f \in A $ be a local function corresponding to $ L $, i.e. $ Y \cap U $ is cut out by $ f=0 $ on $ U $. Then if $ t $ is a local rational function for $ N $, we see immediately from the algebra structure that $\mathcal{O}_X \oplus N \oplus \cdots \oplus N^{n-1} $ is generated by $ t $ as an $ A $-module with the relation $ t^n = f $ i.e. $  (\mathcal{O}_X \oplus N \oplus \cdots \oplus N^{n-1} )(U) = A[t]/t^n - f $. The last ring immediately shows why the relative spec works: $ \operatorname{Spec} (A[t]/t^n - f ) \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec} A $ is an n-sheeted cover ramified precisely along the zero locus of $ f $.

Comment: Dear @Cranium Clamp, do you happen to know a reference which covers this material?  Thank you.

Comment: @Iou unfortunately, I do not have a reference for this.